# I need a script for a splash page that redirects users to one of three pages depending on their cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm a coder but I don't know anything about making and using cookies and if someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I figure I need two short scripts.

1st Script :

script checks for a cookie

if cookie does not exist => show splash page

if cookie exists with a value equal to 1, 2, or 3, redirect to url 1, url 2, or url 3

2nd Script : creates/overwrites cookie with a value of 1, 2, or 3

Done, this is how I did it.

```
First:
if (!isset($_COOKIE['splash_cookie'])) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;
} else {
    $cookieValue = $_COOKIE['splash_cookie'];

    if ($cookieValue == 1) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/1');
        exit;
    } elseif ($cookieValue == 2) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/2');
        exit;
    } elseif ($cookieValue == 3) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/3');
        exit;
    }
}

Second:

    setcookie("splash_cookie", "1", time()+3600);
```

It's not working though, no errors in log, I'll post back when I find the solution.

Comment: Learn how to use cookies... Google is amazing, search for a tutorial and read it. People don't generally just do free work my friend.

Comment: This question shows too little effort and will most likely be closed due to this. It is also unclear if the redirect should be made on the server- or client-side, since the question is tagged with both `php` and `javascript`.

Comment: were happy to help solve problems and to lend expertise working through issues, but stack generally looks down on ops asking other people to "solve it for me".  to better help us help you - show us what you have tried, what you've read and whats not working.  google has tons of information, and you'll typically get a fairly good response taking that approach

Answer (score 3):

Using the jQuery Cookie plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) you can construct an `if` statement (or a `switch` if you prefer) to do whatever you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($.cookie("yourCookieNameHere") = "value1") {
  // do stuff
} else if ($.cookie("yourCookieNameHere") = "value2") {
  // do other stuff
} if ($.cookie("yourCookieNameHere") = "value3") {
  // do the third option
} else {
  // if your cookie doesn't match any of the above...
}
</script>
```

Comment: `$.cookie` is not part of the jQuery library. It would probably be a good idea to declare this in the answer and perhaps add a reference to the jQuery plugin you are using.

Comment: Oops, sorry! So used to using it all of the time that I forgot it was a plugin. Updated my post.